# Proof of $(\neg A \supset A) \supset A$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

As a (total) beginner in logic, I  read this introduction : http://www.loria.fr/~roegel/cours/logique-pdf.pdf (in french). They give an exercise I couldn't achieve. Could someone help me (give an answer or just a clue)?

Using substitution, *modus ponens* and these axioms :

A1 : $(A\lor A)\supset A$

A2 : $B \supset (A \lor B)$

A3 : $(A\lor B) \supset (B \lor A)$

A4 : $(A\lor (B\lor C)) \supset (B\lor(A\lor C))$

A5 : $(B \supset C) \supset ((A\lor B) \supset (A \lor C))$

Prove : $(\neg A \supset A) \supset A$

I tried many combinations of these axioms and rules of inference but not the good one(s).

Thank you

Edit : Here, logical implication $P \supset Q$ is an abbreviation for $\neg P \lor Q$ and $\neg$ is a primitive.

Exercise is left undone on page 19 : "Nous laissons à titre d’exercice la preuve du troisième axiome de Lukasiewicz." $\Rightarrow$ "Prove the third Lukasiewicz axiom using Whitehead and Russell axioms" (page 18)

Comment: I couldn't find the exercise in the course notes you cite. Your axioms say nothing about $\lnot$ and the formula you are trying to prove cannot be derived from them (consider a model in which $\lnot A$ is interpreted as $A$).

Comment: Those are the axioms of W&R's *Principia*, where $\lnot$ is primitive and $\supset$ is an abbreviation; page 18: "$A ⊃ B$ est une abreviation de $¬A ∨ B$".

Comment: See Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, [Principia Mathematica to *56](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA103) (2nd ed - 1927): *2.18, page 103.

Comment: @HenningMakholm There is a proof of $A \supset A$ on [page 19](http://www.loria.fr/~roegel/cours/logique-pdf.pdf) as a lemma to a proof of $\sim A \vee A$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: Yes, I hadn't realized by then that $\supset$ was not supposed to be a primitive.

Comment: @RobArthan: The exercise is unnumbered but in the middle of p. 19 of the linked notes: _"Nous laissons à titre d'exercice la preuve du troisième axiome de Lukasiewicz."_

Comment: I think it would be helpful if some of this detail got edited into the question.

Comment: @RobArthan Just ask for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Double-negation introduction:** $B\supset \neg\neg B$. You know how to derive $\neg B\supset \neg B$, which is an abbreviation for $\neg\neg B\lor \neg B$. Then A3 gives you $\neg B\lor \neg\neg B$, which is the same as $B\supset \neg\neg B$.

**Double-negation elimination:** $\neg\neg A \supset A$. You know how to derive $A\supset A$, which is just $\neg A\lor A$. Now apply double-negation introduction (with $B=\neg A$) to the left-hand side of that (using A3-A5-A3), giving $\neg\neg\neg A\lor A$, which is the same as $\neg\neg A\supset A$.

**Proof by contradiction:** $(\neg A \supset A)\supset A$. The premise $\neg A\supset A$ is the same as $\neg\neg A\lor A$. By A3-A5-A3 with double-negation elimination, this implies $A \lor A$, and A1 then gives you $A$.